# Callback when Ext.NET Combobox local query returns no data

Tags: ext.net

Using Ext.NET combobox.

```
<ext:ComboBox runat="server" 
    ID="ComboBoxCategorizedList" 
    QueryMode="Local" 
    ValueField="Id" 
    EmptyText="Type to begin search..." 
    TypeAhead="false"
    DisplayField="Name"
    Width="500"
    NoteAlign="Down" EnableKeyEvents="true"   
    Note="Press 'Search' icon or Press ENTER for more results"
    RemoveClearTrigger="true">
    <%--Note="Type '*' for a full list"--%>
    <HtmlBin>
        <ext:XScript runat="server">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(window).on("__refresh__", function () {
                    #{ StoreComboBoxCategorizedList }.reload();
                });
            </script>
        </ext:XScript>
    </HtmlBin>  
    <Store>
        <ext:Store runat="server" ID="StoreComboBoxCategorizedList" OnReadData="ComboBoxCategorizedList_ReadData">
            <Proxy>
                <ext:PageProxy />
            </Proxy>
            <Model>
                <ext:Model Id="ModelCategorizedComboBox" runat="server" IDProperty="Id">
                    <Fields>
                        <ext:ModelField Name="Id" />
                        <ext:ModelField Name="Name" />
                        <ext:ModelField Name="Type"  />
                        <ext:ModelField Name="RefId"  />
                        <ext:ModelField Name="Description"  />
                    </Fields>
                </ext:Model>
            </Model>
            <Listeners>
                <Update Handler="#{ComboBoxCategorizedList}.expand();" />
                <EndUpdate Handler="categorizedList();" />
            </Listeners>
            <Parameters>
                <ext:StoreParameter Mode="Raw" Name="filter" Value="#{ComboBoxCategorizedList}.getValue()" />
            </Parameters>
        </ext:Store>
    </Store>
    <Triggers>
        <ext:FieldTrigger Icon="Clear"/>
        <ext:FieldTrigger Icon="Search"></ext:FieldTrigger>
    </Triggers>
    <Listeners>
        <SpecialKey Fn="enterKeyPressHandler" />
        <Expand Handler="categorizedList();" Delay="100" />
        <BeforeSelect Fn="onBeforeSelect" />
        <KeyPress  Handler="#{ComboBoxCategorizedList}.getTrigger(1).onClick();" Buffer="1000" />
        <Change Handler="filterComboxBoxFunction(#{StoreComboBoxCategorizedList}, #{ComboBoxCategorizedList}.getValue()); #{ComboBoxCategorizedList}.expand(); categorizedList();" Delay="100" />
    </Listeners>
```

Not asking for debugging help, but I want to know if an Ext.NET or Extjs dev has a generic solution: Very simply ... I want to initiate a remote search only when the local search returns no records.  So I am looking for the best way to wire this up to the combobox.  I've looked at using the `Expand` event and `BeforeQuery` event but this seems to come up short.

I'm looking for best practices so i can add a "OnLocalQuery" event to my comboboxes; and then take action if the local query returns 0 matches.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function and it works fine .. and without QueryMode="Local":

```
<ext:ComboBox ID="cmb_name" runat="server" FieldLabel="ComboBox" EmptyText="-Select-" HideTrigger="true" TriggerAction="All" SelectOnFocus="true" DisplayField="Name" ValueField="Id" Editable="true" TabIndex="11">
    <Store>
        <ext:Store ID="str_ComboBox" runat="server" PageSize="10">
            <Model>
                <ext:Model ID="mdl_ComboBox" runat="server">
                    <Fields>
                    <ext:ModelField Name="Id" />
                    <ext:ModelField Name="Name" />
                    <ext:ModelField Name="Type"  />
                    <ext:ModelField Name="RefId"  />
                    <ext:ModelField Name="Description"  />
                    </Fields>
                </ext:Model>
            </Model>
        </ext:Store>
    </Store>
    <Listeners>
        <Change Fn="fn_filter" />
    </Listeners>
</ext:ComboBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
var fn_filter = function (_this, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
    var n = 0;
    if (_this.lastQuery == undefined || _this.lastQuery == null) {
        _this.lastQuery = "";
    }
    _this.getStore().clearFilter(true);
    _this.getStore().load();
    _this.store.filter(function (item) {
        if (item.get('Name').includes(_this.getRawValue())) {
            n = n + 1;
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    });
    _this.expand();
    if (n == 0) {
        //returns no records
        //enter code here Callback
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  it's close.  It doesn't seem to allow the combobox to search the local store of values before returning n == 0 and it clears the type ahead in the combo.  But I will work with what you provided.